# Skip certain tests from impacting jenkins build status

Tags: jenkins

I have testNG test suite containing hundreds of tests. Of these, 7 are continually failing and hence the build is unstable (because we have kept the threshold as 0 failures for instability). Is there a way I can tell Jenkins that if certain tests fail, they should not contribute into decision of marking the build as unstable/failed?

I am looking for this solution so that I do not have to disable those 7 tests and keep them running without affecting the daily builds results.

Comment: How about fixing those tests?

Comment: What do you want to achieve by hiding the failing tests ? Only green builds ? IMHO, that is against the rules of game. unless there is a good explanation ?

Comment: @pitseeker, that is not an option because the test failures are caused due to an external library and I don't see them fixing the bug in near future.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizan-Ul-Haq, yes I agree with your point. In my case the failures cannot be fixed by us and they are test only failures which are not triggered by functionality loss, hence I would like to suppress them. If I just disable those tests, I will not able to see at any point of time if the tests are failing due to a new reason but I also do not want to see a yellow build because of these tests regular failure reason.

Comment: @Mukund Is it an option to move these tests into separate build called for example KnownIssues?

Comment: @Mukund - Am not quite sure I understand your situation. You say the failures are due to a bug in an external library and so cannot be fixed. Then what's the point of running those tests. They are going to fail anyways, and if they are not going to be fixed, then you are better off from running them no? Even if the dependent library gets fixed, it would still require that you update your build file to use the reference to the new version right ?

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan yes, the requirement sounds vague but its not the case. The concerned tests are web tests which are failing due to test only failure and hence not much of a concern. I am thinking that if sometime in near future, the tests start failing due to functionality loss, we would not be able to figure it out unless someone has noticed it in manual scenarios. Just because the test was run, we can monitor its status once in a while to ensure that the failure cause is consistent. I am only expecting that this minor monitoring requirement should not keep my build yellow everyday.

Comment: @Mukund - Then you should basically build test listeners that would eavesdrop into the failure of these test failures and if they are known reasons of failure, just mark them as `passed` but add an extra attribute of some sort that would indicate that an expected failure occurred (this would perhaps require a custom reporter as well)

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan, sounds good. I'll see if I can do that